# Someone have an idea how i can calculate the position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nuxt.js

So I have triangles and getting Information of which triangles is on what Connection.
like so:

```
[
{id:3
connected:[2,1,null]}
{id:1
connected:[null,null,3]}
{id:2
connected:[4,3,null]}
{id:4
connected:[2,null,null]}
]
```

It would look like this:

[image]

I need some method to calculate the X- and Y-position and rotation
When i hard code it would look like this:

```
[
        {
          id: 3,
          x: 200,
          y: 200,
          radius: 100,
          rotation: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          x: 300,
          y: 150,
          radius: 100,
          rotation: 180,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          x: 200,
          y: 310,
          radius: 100,
          rotation: 180,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          x: 300,
          y: 360,
          radius: 100,
          rotation: 0,
        },
]
```

Comment: are you sure about the coordinates? actually you get not a symmetrically result, if you add more triangles.

Comment: in real the triangles are LED-triangles and i have to picture them on a website

Comment: Your question is interesting, It would be easy, If I know the output, Also you provide an `Array_Of_Object:{ id,x,y,radius,rotation }[]` it that your expected output ?